# Custom log for each user with Serilog

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side, serilog

I am trying to create a custom logger based on serilog. The application i am building is based on net6 blazor-server-side.
The goal is that every time a user logs into the application, I create a specific log file for him.

First I create a dependency injection in the program.cs

file Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICustomLogger>( s => new CustomLogger());
```

In the Customlogger class, I initialize the loggerconfiguration in the constructor

file CustomLogger.cs

```
        private ILogger<CustomLogger> _logger;


        protected readonly LoggerConfiguration _loggerConfig;

        public CustomLogger()
        {
            _loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug();
        }
```

In the Login.razor , once the login is successful, I call the CreateLogger method, passing the username as a parameter (this is to create a specific folder)

file CustomLogger.cs

```
        public void CreateLogger(string username)
        {
            var l = _loggerConfig.WriteTo.File($"./Logs/{username}/log_.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileCountLimit: 30).CreateLogger();


            _logger = new SerilogLoggerFactory(l).CreateLogger<CustomLogger>(); // creates an instance of ILogger<CustomLogger>
        }
```

Beyond that, I've created methods to write the various log levels

file CustomLogger.cs

```
        public void LogInformation(string m)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(m);
        }

        public void LogError(string m)
        {
            _logger.LogError(m);
        }

        public void LogWarning(string m)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning(m);
        }
```

The Customlogger class is bound to the ICustomLogger interface

file ICustomLogger.cs

```
    public interface ICustomLogger
    {

        void LogInformation(string m);

        void LogError(string m);

        void LogWarning(string m);

        void CreateLogger(string username);

        ILogger<CustomLogger> GetLogger();
    }
```

For the moment I see that the system works, if I connect with a user, his folder and the file are created, and so on for each user.

My question is :

- Could this approach cause problems?
- Is it already possible to do this via Serilog?

Thanks for your time

N.

**UPDATE**

the system works well in the login page, for each user to create his own logger, but as soon as I move to the index page, the constructor of the CustomLogger class is called and the ILogger is null.
I thought AddScoped was only called once for "session"

Is it possible to call AddSingleton every time the user logs in, that way the specific dependency remains for as long as needed?

**UPDATE 2**

I changed the injection, now I use AddSingleton

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IOramsLoggerService>(s => new OramsLoggerService());
```

Inside the OramsLoggerService class, I created a list of loggers, which is filled at each login

OramsLoggerSerivce.cs

```
    public class OramsLoggerService : IOramsLoggerService
    {

        private List<OramsLogger> loggers;

        public OramsLoggerService()
        {
            loggers = new List<OramsLogger>();
        }
        public void CreateLogger(string? username)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("username");
            }

            if (loggers.Where(x => x.Username == username).Count() > 0)
            {
                return;
            }


            // characters not allowed in the folder name
            string originaUsername = username;
            username = username.Replace("<", "-");
            username = username.Replace(">", "-");
            username = username.Replace(":", "-");
            username = username.Replace("/", "-");
            username = username.Replace("\\", "-");
            username = username.Replace("|", "-");
            username = username.Replace("?", "-");
            username = username.Replace("*", "-");
            username = username.Replace("\"", "-");

            var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug();

            var l = loggerConfig.WriteTo.File($"./Logs/{username}/log_.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileCountLimit: 100).CreateLogger();


            var logger = new SerilogLoggerFactory(l).CreateLogger<OramsLogger>(); // creates an instance of ILogger<OramsLogger>

            loggers.Add(new OramsLogger(logger, originaUsername));

        }
    }
```

by doing so, I have all the loggers created in the other pages available.

The OramsLogger class contains the logger and the username.
I use the username to search the list, I think I'll change it to the id in the future.

OramsLogger.cs

```
    public class OramsLogger
    {
        public ILogger<OramsLogger> logger;


        public string Username { get; set; }

        public OramsLogger(ILogger<OramsLogger> l, string username)
        {
            logger = l;
            Username = username;
        }
    }
```

For the moment I have created 1000 dummy users when I login with my user and it seems to work.

Could this be a good approach?

Answer (score 1):

For user-level custom logs, this method is appropriate.

There are no particular concerns.